# Why is oil used as the lubricant in power generators, while water is the most available, cheapest and accessible lubricant?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, water-resources

The lower viscosity of water reduces friction.  Besides, the water can transfer heat way better than oils.  So why not use water as a lubricant in wind or hydro turbines, especially on equipment which is operating in the ocean ...

It seems to be a perfect material.  It's the most abundant liquid on Earth, and it causes no ecological damage.

Comment: Ocean water is salty increasing corrosion issues unless you purify it...

Comment: I think my question on physics.SE might be of interest for you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259501/why-is-oil-a-better-lubricant-than-water

Comment: Why do you think a lower viscosity would be a good thing in a bearing lubricant? :)

Comment: @Luaan Smaller friction!

Comment: Vacuum doesn't have friction. Why don't we use vacuum bearings? :P (funnily, we actually do - but they're rather special).

Comment: The chemical properties of water being a nearly universal solvent that can also easily become an acid or oxidizer as well as vaporize or freezer under most working temperatures make it less than an ideal lubricant in most long duration applications.

Comment: If water works well as a lubricant, then why can't we put it in our car engines, etc.? Think about the consequences of that, friend.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The whole point of lubrication is to keep the two surfaces almost apart.

Water has low viscosity in comparison to oil-based lubricants, which means that it forms a thinner film (electrohydrodynamic film thickness) between the two surfaces; the thinner the film, the greater the chance of direct physical contact between the parts.

So, the higher viscosity actually can be useful here. Another thing about water is that its viscosity doesn’t increase by pressure, unlike oil-based lubricants, as usually, the two surfaces are operating under pressure.

Oils are better vibration dampers than water.

As @SolarMike mentioned in the comments, water is extremely corrosive and can also dissolve many destructive elements.

Thanks to the capillary effect, water molecules can penetrate into micro-cracks on/beneath the surface of parts.  Once there, due to extreme pressure, those molecules can decompose into hydrogen and oxygen, and build up pressure in the cracks, which leads to crack propagation and failure. This phenomenon is called Hydrogen embrittlement.

Water also provides a very good environment for fungi and other living microorganisms, which decay and changes the PH of the water, usually a shift toward an acidic environment, which in turn also corrodes the steel.

Comment: Hydrogen embrittlement is not related to crack propagation, because hydrogen has no reason to stay in a crack. It creates cracks that are not open to the surface, inside the material. It is outright spooky to me.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad do you have a source for H2O decomposition under high pressure? I never heard of such an effect, and I find it very surprising that such an effect exists, but then if it does, I'd like an authoritative confirmation. (In general I'd worry more about the oxygen radical than the hydrogen embrittlement in that situation, but then again I do not have enough background about physical and chemical dynamics under high pressure to be certain.)

Comment: @toolforger I encountered the concept in a chapter called tribology when I was attending at the college, the course was fracture mechanics I think. I don't have any insight into the physical phenomenon at all. Better ask in Physic stack.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad hydrogen embrittlement is a well-known effect. It's H2O decomposition that I am questioning; if you do not have a reference, you should probably remove it from your answer.

Comment: Also, Water expands as it freezes.

Comment: @toolforger Since the question isn't about the phenomenon at all, I don't see any reason to remove it. Electrocatalytic materials with high activity (some kind of steels) , in combination with pressure results in water splitting. Again the question is not about how this happens. Maybe OP has something to say here.

Comment: @SimonRichter Dynamic systems require lubrication, as water flows it never freezes, in wind and hydro generators parts sliding pretty fast on each other so the lubricant would warm up, sometimes up to some tens of degrees. It can well causes some problems in special applications.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad The reason to remove it would be because it is providing _incorrect_ information, when the information isn't even required.  Some quick searching seems to suggest that high pressure actually _prevents_ the decomposition; while heat and low pressure are actually more likely to cause it.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad Wow... aggressive response much?  Your answer doesn't mention electrocatalysts.  I don't see why you're attacking me for calling out things lacking in your answer.  I'm specifically questioning the claim that increased pressure leads to decomposition; because from what I understand, it is the opposite.  I don't see why you would go on the offensive instead of just supporting the information you've provided.

Comment: I don't think that's an accurate characterization of hydrogen embrittlement, either. You described a phenomenon with several stages, none of which is hydrogen absorption or brittleness (a type of weakening) being caused.

Comment: @JMac It's difficult to decipher the tone in the text! My comment was not nice I agree, but I was not being aggressive! I do believe in freedom of speech, which is being violated, one of the moderators deleted my comment. If you think the answer is wrong, then downvote it, don't instruct me to remove the answer.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I didn't instruct you to delete the answer... like at all.  I pointed out that part of this answer seems unsupported, and that it wasnt needed. 
I don't see why you would keep it in the answer if you can't find any sources to support it.  Also, freedom of speech isn't relevant here.  This is a private website, freedom of speech doesn't apply.

Answer (score 12):

Sea water is about the worst thing in the world to put in a metallic mechanical device. As noted , corrosion would be horrendous ; dissimilar metals, stray currents , etc. Wind turbine gearing is an exceptionally demanding application ; EP ( extreme pressure ) lubes are needed with graphite and/or moly sulfide, etc. I am sure a major problem addressed by wind machine engineers for off shore applications , is sealing the lube systems to keep salt and moisture out. Not the least of problems is that water has little/no lubricity qualities like film strength.

Comment: *Aqua regia* would be worse ...

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica My intuition immediately found hydrochloric acid. Sure, aqua regia destroys the surface fast. But hydrochloric acid makes any surfaces that it's vapors reach corrode, if they can. Slow, but not much better. If the surfaces are complex, much worse.

Answer (score 4):

Great question!  Water absolutely *is* used as a lubricant in some power generating systems.  For example many Francis style turbines use their feed water as the primary lubricant and coolant of the bottom main bearing.  (In the old Loeffel turbines, that bearing was typically made of lignum vitae wood, and could last up to 100 years in near constant use).  Good engineering takes advantage of the cheap availability of water whenever applicable.

But water freezes and expands, blowing apart your engines, so it's not suitable for every application.  This is enough of an everyday issue that automobiles are designed with "freeze plugs" and block heater ports and typically use toxic and environmentally unfriendly antifreeze chemicals in their liquid coolant systems.  If your generator fails in cold weather, you don't want it to freeze solid before you can manage to repair it.

(A freeze plug, also called a Welch plug, is a core hole plug purposely made weak enough that it will fail before the block cracks due to frozen coolant.  Core holes are left by the block casting process.)

And although absolutely pure water is an electrical insulator in the laboratory, in real life it's not, because even the slightest amount of contamination makes water an excellent electrical conductor.  Oils, on the other hand, typically have consistently low conductivity until they are so loaded with metal contaminants that they have lost lubricity.  If your generator has an oil leak, the oil won't provide a conductive path to repair technicians and other system parts.

And finally, as others have already noted, water is very corrosive, especially seawater.  Since rust expands to five times the size of the steel it came from, you can't use any of the cheap iron alloys in water, which drives up the cost of materials pretty quickly.

Petroleum oils are a superb lubricant, able to be purified and recycled many times.  At least as early as 1915 intelligent people were writing that burning fuels like petroleum is a criminal waste of a fantastically valuable and limited resource; it's robbing future generations in order to turn our shared treasure into atmospheric poisons.  It's nice to see people like yourself thinking about these things!

Comment: Great point about insulation, I forgot it in my post. @SamB

Comment: Might be good to mention the low boil point for water as well.

Comment: @axsvl77, yes, very true.  Not a problem in high flow rate turbines but certainly a big issue in closed loop systems.

Answer (score 0):

### *Lubricity* is a material quality

Look into the difficulties they have had removing sulfur from diesel fuel.  Sulfur was added (or not removed) to increase the lubricity of the diesel fuel, to improve freedom of motion in injection pumps.  That being missing is a hardship for older diesel engines whose pumps depend on it.  The fuel is basically the same in other respects, but for this lubricity factor.   This is easily restored with as little as 2% biodiesel.

So here you have these two liquids, mineral diesel and biodiesel - that are both seemingly the same.  But one is "slick" and the other not.  That property is **lubricity**, and that is the very thing you need in a lubricating oil.

Water has none.